# Why is $W$ boson decay more favorable for strange quark than $Z$ decay?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, weak-interaction

As seen below, a strange quark decays into a down quark and a neutral pion. Why is the top decay more likely than the bottom decay?

[image]

edit: is it because of this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor-changing_neutral_current

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 4):

The article you are linking distinctly says that FCNC in the SM could *only occur beyond the tree level*. (They are further greatly suppressed at the one-loop level by the GIM mechanism, etc, but this is irrelevant to your question.)

The lowermost $\bar s d Z$ vertex in your 2nd diagram fails to exist.

In the SM lagrangian, the Z boson couples generation-diagonally to  all fermions, including the quarks in your question. The reason is evident, if only you looked up the neutral currents in your text: Both the hypercharge and the EM current cannot fail to be flavor diagonal. The interaction states and mass eigenstates are identical, and there is no possibility for misalignment, as you get in the charged current couplings.

Answer (score 1):

The interaction with Z boson is impossible. The strange quark will stay a strange quark and will not change. Nothing like this exists because the flavor of the quarks still remain. In the case of the W boson charge change overrides this and the change in flavor can occur with W bosons.